# Kotlin class in other package not resolved

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code

I started with Kotlin and want to exclude files in other packages in Visual Studio Code. Unfortunately it does not work

*Person.kt*

```
package com.example

public class Person(
    val _firstName: String,
    val _lastName: String,
    val _age: Int
)
```

*main.kt*

```
import com.example.Person

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val person = Person("Peter","Pan",12)
    println(person)
}
```

When I hover over in the main function Visual Studio Code show me the Person class, thus it seems that it is recogniced but as far as I run the code I get the following error

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Matthias\Desktop\Kotlin\" && kotlinc Main.kt -include-runtime -d Main.jar && java -jar Main.jar
Main.kt:1:12: error: unresolved reference: example
import com.example.Person
           ^
Main.kt:4:18: error: unresolved reference: Person
    val person = Person("Peter","Pan",12)
                 ^
```

I played around with other package names like "domain" but then the whole class is not found. I put them in folder but the error stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are compiling only Main.kt, it doesn't include Person in the Main.jar being built for running. As you are referring to Person in the code, it should be part of the jar.

Comment: But I import the class, why is it not recognized? How can I include the Jar?